# How to change the starting xml inside main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to figure out to how I could change the loaded xml when app is started. Currently it opens activity_main.xml. Is there any way to make the app open my info.xml(Which is also at my side navigation bar) without creating a new activity?

Main Activity code with changed setcontentview:

```
package com.example.cubehelppp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.info);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new SecondFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new ThirdFragment())
                .commit();

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_info_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new InfoFragment())
                .commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

My info.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <TextView


        android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"






       android:text="@string/welcome_to_app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/version"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="Version 0.1"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />



 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/About"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="CubeHelppp is a cubing application with contains algorithms to 3x3x3. currently OLL, PLL and F2L. In some update soon adding more algorithms to cover wca puzzles! "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/patchnotes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="Patchnotes"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/patch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/patchnotes"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-300dp"
        android:text="-App published with 3x3x3 algorithms"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/patch2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/patch1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/version"
        android:text="-Bugs fixed"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

All of the bugs I got when changed setcontentview:

[Bugs that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LnZJ.png)

And then it just crashes. I have tried to create a new activity but didn't get them to work.

Comment: Can you post your info.xml?

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella Added it now

Comment: The problem is that `drawer_layout` is not in your `info.xml`. If you post the code of your `activity_main.xml` i can will suggest you the correct layout

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella did that too

Comment: Sorry but i'm need too your `app_bar_main.xml`

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella just gonna learn creating activities..... I think its easier

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thanks for info and help im gonna now focus on creating new activity and getting it to work!

Comment: We do not allow posts to be deleted here after an answer is received. If you have additional solution material you would like to post in order to help others, feel free to post an answer. Your "deleted" post in any case was very visible in the edit history. It is worth noting that most snippets of code have zero value from an intellectual property perspective, since they can be trivially recreated by any reasonably competent engineer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change started activity on AndroidManifest.
Like this:

```
   <activity android:name=".HomePage" />
            <activity android:name=".LoginPage">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

This LoginPage is, first page when started app. HomePage is other activity. You can change them.